# Javascript: Unrecognized expression due to rails code in class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
$(".collapse.summary_row_<%= pin %>").each(function() {
      var thisId = $(this).find('#pin').text();
      var sumVal = parseFloat($(this).find('#price').text());

      var $rowsToGroup = $(this).nextAll('tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('#pin').text() === thisId;
      });

      $rowsToGroup.each(function() {
        sumVal += parseFloat($(this).find('#price').text());
        $(this).remove();
      });

      $(this).find('#price').text(sumVal);
    });
```

---

```
<tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="summary_row_<%=pin%>" data-
target=".summary_row_<%= pin %>">
<td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
<td> <%= pin%> </td>
<td align="right"> <strong> <%= number_to_currency(amount, unit: "", 
precision: 2) if amount %> </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr id="child_row_<%=pin%>" class="collapse summary_row_<%= pin %>" 
align="right" >
  <td class="child_data_<%=pin%>"><strong>Year</strong></td>
  <td><strong>Quarter</strong></td>
  <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
</tr>

<% if detail %>
<% detail.each do |key, value| %>
<tr id="child_row_<%=pin%>" class="collapse summary_row_<%= pin %>" 
bgcolor="#fba993" align="right" >
  <td class="child_data_<%=pin%>" id="pin"><%= value[0]%></td>
  <td id="quart"><%= value[1]%></td>
  <td id="price"><%= number_to_currency(value[2], unit: "", precision: 2) %>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

The code above is the Javascript code and the code below is the html/ruby code. I'm trying to make it so that when the .clickable tr class gets clicked, the function will do it's work, but it doesn't and I get this message instead:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .collapse.summary_row_<%= pin %>
```

I've noticed that the other functions in my JS files worked, but they do not have the ruby syntax inside their class names so I'm assuming that the ruby code has something to do with this error.

Comment: is the ruby code executed on a server?

Comment: Yes I believe so, they are being taken from a database (mySQL)

Answer (score 0):

You're writing Rails Code inside JavaScript file, it will not work there, you have to write your rails code inside `html.erb` file or you can call that function inside `<script>` tag from `html.erb` file or you can use dynamic `data attributes` inside your html tags

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Ruby variable in your Javascript you should add erb extension to your JS file: `my_file.js.erb`.

Other option is to use directly `my_file.coffee`. Here you can change adapt your JS file [JsToCoffee](http://js2.coffee/)

Hope it helps,